# Can Room of Requirements give you gold?

Tags: harry-potter

The room of requirement in Harry Potter gives you what you require, Harry Potter used it for DA meetings, Dumbledore used it once when filled with chamber pots as well. If a wizard desperately needs money, can it be filled with gold?

The Weasleys could have really used the gold.

Comment: Leave it as the "gold" part, otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: I want to say "no, it can't" but I'm darned if I can come up with a sensible reason why not!

Comment: Well it seemed to give the DA a lot of tools and instruments and books. I don't remember ever taking any of the things out of the room. Maybe what happens in room of requirement stays in room of requirement.

Comment: @Bernad, no, because we know Filch used it to obtain cleaning supplies.  Gold is *probably* ruled out [as discussed here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24803/5930) but things like text-books ought to work as far as I can see.  Perhaps the RoR has a built-in DRM system. :-)

Comment: It's a long time since I read HP, but didn't the room create the passage to Hogsmead because Neville was hungry and, since the room couldn't produce food, it created the means to obtain it?

Comment: @Nicola Talbot Maybe it can create a hidden passage to a Gringotts vault.

Comment: I think we could just call it the Room of Deus Ex Machina.

Answer (score 11):

No, as Gold is suspected to be one of the 5 exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration.

It's also mentioned that only the Philosopher's Stone, which is a rare and unique object, can give the user unlimited gold and life. One logical way we can get around is "Information" - If the room can give us anything not included in the 5 exceptions to Gamp's Law, we can simply ask for information to create a Philosopher's Stone. This is akin to *wishing for more genies*

UPDATE: [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59279/88061) answer contains quotes by JK saying that transfigured gold, much like leprechaun gold, doesn't last:

References:

1. [What Are the Other Four Exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24803/what-are-the-other-four-exceptions-to-gamps-law-of-elemental-transfiguration)
2. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59279/88061

Comment: I'm sure I saw an answer the other day (turns out it was this one https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185359/did-ariana-dumbledores-portrait-dig-the-tunnel-to-hogwarts) which said that TRoR created a tunnel. It makes you wonder if it could create a tunnel into Gringots!

Comment: Wild fan speculation is not a good source to base answers off of.

Comment: True, I agree - that's why I talked about the philosopher's stone point too. With this question, I don't think we'll find an exact answer in canon - but assuming wizards accept gold as a standard of value, we might assume that they'd choose something that is not replicable - the exception being the philosopher's stone, which is said to be the end game of alchemy. So it's a good guess that gold cannot be easily replicated. But yeah, I agree, this need not be true. The reasons for selecting the various items for gamp's law are answered in the respective question

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought not, because what the Room of Requirements provides is what you need *right now*, and gold is not something that anyone needs. What you need is something you can buy with the gold, but in that case the Room will provide you with that thing directly, instead of making you haul a load of gold to a shop.

The one exception would be if someone has made an Unbreakable Vow to pay someone some gold, and with ten minutes to go you absolutely have to have gold and nothing else.

Comment: Unbreakable Vow, a bet with a bookie, whatever :-)